# Visual Studio Slow Build With Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

Starting a few months ago I noticed that when a WPF project is out of date, it builds much more slowly than other projects. This seems to have started with Visual Studio 2012, though I'm not positive about that.

So my question is, are there any settings or tools I could use to help diagnose performance problems with the build process? I have enabled extra logging for C++ projects in the past to determine why VS thinks a project needs to be rebuilt when it hasn't changed. Is something like that available for other types of projects?

Comment: do you have ReSharper or other type plugins?

Comment: No. I do have some of the standard extensions like Nuget. I have one that renames your window title to include parts of the path (so you can differentiate between the same solution opened from two different branches). But that's it. Nothing like resharper.

Comment: Then you may want to check through any binding redirects that crept in or otherwise might be in place (in your app config or manifest).  They can be hellish.  Short of that, my standard protocol is to remove the suo file and the bin/obj directories.